Number of ring homomorphisms from a quotient ring R/I to an arbitrary ring R'
I want to determine a general method for finding the number of homomorphisms between a quotient ring R/I to an arbitrary ring R'.
My attempted solution:
There is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of all ideals of R/I and homomorphic images of R/I. Moreover, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of all ideals of R/I to the set of all ideals of R containing I.
Hence, finding all homomorphism from R/I to R' boils down to finding all homomorphisms from R to R' with I contained in the kernel. Moreover, if the homomorphism from R/I to R' sends unity to unity, this must be preserved for the homomorphism between R to R'. Is this correct?
Application to a particular problem
Let p be a prime number. Consider the ring R = $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-px)$ with multiplicative identity denoted by 1'. Find the number of ring homomorphisms from R to $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(1') = 1$.
My answer:
It is sufficient to find the number of homomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ with $(x^2-px)$ contained in the kernel. As $\phi(1) = 1$, we just need to determine the image of x. As $\phi(x^2-px) = 0, x = 0$ or $p$. Thus, the answer is 2. Is this correct?
Laslty, it does not seems I use the fact that p is prime anywhere. Is this condition required, and does the answer change if p is not prime?
